# average accuracy calculation

Tags: probability, accuracy

Can you help me to calculate this accuracy?

P(A)= 0.10 and P(B)= 0.90

What is the average accuracy , if it randomly guessed a class label (with probability 0.5 A and probability 0.5 B) for each sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're essentially flipping a coin where one side is $A$ and the other is $B$ and you want to see how frequently you are correct.

Then, we seek to find $P(\text{A occurs and A is guessed or B occurs and B is guessed}).$

Assuming your choice is independent of the accuracy and assuming that $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, then we have:

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{A occurs and A is guessed or B occurs and B is guessed}) &=& 
P(\text{A occurs and A is guessed}) + P(\text{B occurs and B is guessed})- P(\text{A occurs and A is guessed and B occurs and B is guessed}) \\
&=&
P(\text{A occurs and A is guessed}) + P(\text{B occurs and B is guessed}) \\ &=& 
P(\text{A occurs})\times P(\text{A is guessed}) + P(\text{B occurs})\times P(\text{B is guessed}) \\
&=& 0.1\times 0.5 + 0.9\times 0.5 \\
&=& 0.5
\end{eqnarray*}
$
Assuming those assumptions above, your answer should be 50% accuracy.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to classify spam and non spam in emails. I know that the probability of getting spam is 0.1 and getting non spam is 0.9. I will classify each mail as spam or non spam with probability 0.5. I want to find average accuracy on this approach. I think your formula seems true for this question. Thanks.